# SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request

Tags: android

I am using `soap base web service`.. In one of example i am able to do parsing and get response but when i try for different one i am getting below mentioned errors in my project my code is below pls take a look..